# C Pointer to Pointer and Pass by Reference

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to learn C, and I'm hung up a bit on Pointers to Pointers. I think I understand why you need them, but can't quite get my head wrapped around what is happening.

For instance, the following code doesn't seem to work as I would expect it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int newp(char **p) {
  char d = 'b';
  *p = &d;
  /*printf("**p = %c\n", **p);*/
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  char c = 'a';
  char *p = &c;
  int result;

  result = newp(&p);
  printf("result = %d\n", result);
  printf("*p = %c\n", *p);
  printf("c = %c\n", c);

  return 0;
}
```

The result I get is this:

```
result = 1
*p = 
c = a
```

*p prints as nothing. Instead, I would expect `*p = b`.

**However**, if I uncomment line 6 (the `printf` in the `newp` function), then I get this:

```
**p = b
result = 1
*p = b
c = a
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are dealing with undefined behaviour. The variable `d` is local (resides on the stack) and is not available after the enclosing function (`newp`) returns.

When dereferencing `p` outside `newp`, the address on the stack `&d` may be overwritten by some other local variable or it may contain garbage.

Comment: Thank you! Coming from Ruby and other dynamic languages, I forget that the C compiler is less forgiving on scope.

Comment: 1) It's not the compiler; it's the language specification. 2) C allows for more fine-grained control over scope, but that's not the real problem here. The problem is that C has value semantics by default and expects you to do manual memory management. (Putting things on the stack and letting them die at the end of the function is a form of this.) The "other dynamic languages" have reference semantics by default, and keep the underlying values around until garbage collection algorithms kick in.

Answer (score 7):

You are storing the address of a local variable (`d`) in `*p` and then dereferencing it when the variable has gone out of scope. [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Thank you - that seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 2):

You might be "missing" the keyword `static`, as in:

```
int newp(char **p) {
    static char d = 'b';   /* <--- HERE */
    *p = &d;
    /*printf("**p = %c\n", **p);*/
    return 1;
}
```

This `static` keyword causes the compiler to locate the local variable in "static storage," which continues to exist (i.e. maintains its value) during the time periods after `newp()` has been called.  However, there is only *one* copy of this memory -- each subsequent invocation of the containing function (`newp`) re-uses the same memory location and may overwrite the value at that time.

Without the `static` keyword to qualify your local variable declaration, the storage will be "automatic", which means that it is automatically discharged from current use after the containing function has returned.  After `newp` returns, the memory formerly used for the local variable can be reused for any purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Here *pointer means that the parameter that this function 
// will expect will be a pointer. 
void changeViaPointer(int *pointer);

// Pointer of a pointer.
void changeViaPointerInBetween(int **pointer);

int main(){

    int number;
    number = 20;

    // Here *pointer means that the variable that is declared will be a pointer.
    int *pointer;

    // Actually asigning value to the pointer variable.
    pointer = &number;

    // Pointer of a pointer.
    int **pointerInBetween;

    // Assigning value to the pointer of a pointer. 
    // Assigning the memory location where this pointer points to. 
    // So this is a pointer in between.
    pointerInBetween = &pointer;

    printf("The number before changing is %d\n", number);

    // Pass the pointer variable.
    changeViaPointer(pointer);
    printf("The number after pointer changing is %d\n", number);

    // Pass the pointer of a pointer variable.
    changeViaPointerInBetween(pointerInBetween);
    printf("The number after pointer in between changing is %d\n", number);

    return 0;
}

void changeViaPointer(int *pointer){

    // Okay, at this point we have received a variable called pointer,
    // which points to some value. In order to access this value
    // we need to use *pointer.
    // BUT THIS IS DIFFERENT FROM THE *pointer IN THE FUNCTION DECLARATION!!!
    *pointer = *pointer + 20;
}

void changeViaPointerInBetween(int **pointer){

    // **pointer explanation:
    // Only pointer is the memory location
    // *pointer  is the value of that memory location, which in this specific case is also a memory location
    // **pointer is the value of what the other pointer points to.
    **pointer = **pointer + 20;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did, just including a code snippet does not help the OP, or any user to gain insight from this answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I think if you concentrate on the code I have attached for  a minute, you can understand more than reading tons of text. If there is still something not clear, you can mention that and I will do by best to explain. Thanks a lot for the comment!

Comment: I agree the comments are very verbose and explanatory, however giving an intro before giving a solution, and a closing remark helps sum up the OP's answer: `what am I doing wrong`? Though by giving this solution you may help the OP solve their issue, you don't directly address that question, with something like `"Therefore you were simply doing it this way rather than this, etc."`